# asp repeater itemcommand not working on second click

Tags: repeater, onclientclick

I have a repeater which I bind the data using Bind method from the database. There is a Asp:Button with an **onclientclick** and **onclick** event. In OnClientClick I open a new window and onclick I am adding the data to the database. This works perfectly on the first Page load. After first click on any of the buttons in the repeater, the click events stops working on subsequent clicks.

I have spending hours on finding a solution for the same, can any one guide me where  i am going wrong what needs to be done.

P.S: My application is AJAX Enabled , using WCF and JQUERY

Thanks & Regards,
Phani...

Comment: pasting your relevant code behind and aspx may help

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind I got it solved my self. For others who are trying to solve the same issue, here is the solution:

The code below opens up a new window with out popup blocker blocking the window

OnClientClick of the button write Javascript like below to open a new window and refresh the parent window (*I have to do this as the ItemCommand event was not firing until the page is refreshed*)

```
OnClientClick = "target='_blank'; setTimeout("location.reload(true);", timeout);
```

Phani...

Comment: If any one know of any other solution. Please feel free to post here